# How to find and extract the audio files from Skyrim?

Tags: the-elder-scrolls-v-skyrim

I'd like to get the shout sounds from Skyrim. I bought the soundtrack but they contain just the music and not the shouts. I'd like to get the actual shouts.

Does anyone know how to get audio from Skyrim?

Comment: I think the general question is too broad to answer here, since two different games probably won't use the same format.

Comment: @svick My bad, I just edited the question and made it clearer that it is for Skyrim.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need a bsa extractor.
Skyrim - Sounds.bsa is the file you are looking for. Not sure if there is one for skyrim yet but the old oblivion ones might work if they haven't changed the fileformat too much.

Comment: I've used one of the oblivion ones to fix the bug with Esbern.

Comment: @Fambida This is the [BSA Unpacker](http://www.tesnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=3117) I used to fix the Esbern no voice bug: http://www.tesnexus.com/downloads/file.php?id=3117